# How to remember input history in Tkinter Entry after converting with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm building a GUI app using Tkinter, then I convert into one exe file using pyinstaller `--onefile`

It's required from me that the Entry text box **remembers the previous history of input**. So that when the user clicks on the Entry box, is shows previous entered values and then the user can **choose one of them**.

Please note that this should take place in the one exe file and it remembers history even after closing.

I've already thought about creating a text file when starting the app, where it can store input history. And keep the text file even after closing the app, then checking the file when reopening the app. That's doable. ***But how to display the input history when clicking the Entry box and then choosing one of the history inputs?***

Comment: You would probably need to set up a menu that pops up at the base of the entry field. The entry field would probably be linked to a function that checks the current typed data to a list of previously entered values and then display them as long as the entry field has focus.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so my example might be more complicated than it needs to be but I could not figure out how to get menu to work in this case without it causing problems with typing in the entry field.

My example uses a `Toplevel()` window as the menu for holding the previously entered values with a partial match.

The idea is to keep a record of previously entered stuff by binding `Return` to a function that records the entry field and then checking all recorded values against what is currently in the entry field by binding all keys to a checking function.

Using a tracking variable we can keep track of if a toplevel window exist or not and also make sure we do not display a toplevel window if no matches are found.

One issues I have not yet figured out is removing the borders from the buttons so they look more like a traditional drop down menu.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("150x100")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.list_previous_entries = []
        self.top_menu = None
        self.entry.bind("<Key>", lambda event: self.check_previous_entries(event))
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.record_previous_entries)

    def check_previous_entries(self, event=None):
        xx = self.entry.get().strip()  
        list_partial_matches = []
        if xx.strip() != "":
            x = self.entry.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.entry.winfo_rooty()
            try:
                self.top_menu.destroy()
            except:
                print("No active top")

            for item in self.list_previous_entries:
                    if xx in item:
                        list_partial_matches.append(item)  

            if list_partial_matches != []: 
                self.top_menu = tk.Toplevel(self)
                self.top_menu.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x, y+20))
                self.top_menu.overrideredirect(1)
                for item in list_partial_matches:
                    tk.Button(self.top_menu, text=item, highlightthickness=0,
                              command=lambda i=item: self.select_word(i), anchor="w").pack(fill="x")
        else:
            if self.top_menu != None:
                self.top_menu.destroy()
                self.top_menu = None

        self.entry.focus()

    def record_previous_entries(self, event):
        print("test2")
        x = self.entry.get()
        if x not in self.list_previous_entries:
            self.list_previous_entries.append(x)

    def select_word(self, word):
        self.entry.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry.insert(0, word)
        self.top_menu.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk() 
    MyApp = App(root).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Results:

Here is what you get when you type 3 different words save each one.

[image]

By clicking on any of the buttons displayed it will replace what is in the entry field with that word.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll try it and if it works, I'll accept the answer even though I was hoping for a simpler solution. But looks like this is the only way.

Comment: @AhmedWas it is probably not the only way. It is just the method I was able to come up with. I am sure there is a better way. I just have not been able to find one.